# Return master rows based on detail filter

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, master-detail

I have a query where I want to return Master rows based on whether the detail fulfil a certain criteria.

For example, I only want to return a particular Master row if AT LEAST one of the Detail rows have SomeProperty = X.

Based on the following predicate:

```
        predicate = predicate.And(p =>
                                  p.BasketItems.Where(obi => obi.BasketItemTypeID ==
                                                                  (int) BasketType.Refund).Count() > 0);
```

generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[BasketItems] AS [t3]
    WHERE ([t3].[BasketId] = [t0].[OrderBasketID]) AND ([t3].[BasketItemTypeID] = 3)
    )) > 0)
```

Problem with this is it's doing a table scan, so the query takes a while to run.

Just checking that I'm not doing anything crazy and wonder if there's anything that can speed up this query?

Thanks
Duncan

Comment: I don't see where 't0' is defined in the query you posted.  I suspect it refers to a 'Basket' table, but it would be helpful if you could post the entire query.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Bob, that's just a snippet of the full query but I wanted to keep the question nice and concise!  t0 in this case would be the Master table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select M.basketID, max(M.field1) as field1, max(M.field2) as field2 
from dbo.basketItems as M
Inner join detail on M.basketID = detail.basketID
where detail.basketItemTypeID = '3'
group by M.basketID
```

(Join master to detail.  select all rows where detail has the required criterion.  Squish the resulting rows down to 1 per master record.)